# Coolidge tube and X-rays production

Tags: x-rays

I have two questions about the [Coolidge tube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_tube#Coolidge_tube_(hot_cathode_tube)) :

1. Why do electrons emit X-rays but not other wavelengths as well ?
2. Why is the intensity of the characteristic spectrum higher than the bremsstrahlung itensity ?

My book doesnt make it clear , thanks so much !

Answer (score 1):

One does get Bremsstrahlung all the way, At synchrotron sources this is also used in the infrared, especially in experiments on surfaces.

In an anode material, I do not think it is generally true that there is more emission in the characteristic lines than in the continuum.